# What versions of Windows does MS-SQL come pre-installed on?

Tags: windows, installation, ms-sql

We have an emergency mgmt. application that runs on a flash drive so that in an emergency a PC can be commandeered to run the app. We are considering using MS-SQL instead of MS-Access, so I am wondering if MS-SQL comes pre-installed and ready to run on any Windows O/S and if so which.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None.

SQLExpress is good, but requires that you install the service on each PC that will run the app. A better alternative would be [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlexpress/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express), which requires no server process and can be rolled right into your app, making it more portable. Kind of like how SQLite can be integrated into apps.

Answer (score 3):

not by default, no. you can download the Free SQLExpress package if you like, there aren't any skus that come with it by default.